# How to Upgrade PHP from 5.4.16 to >= PHP 5.6.5 / PHP 7 on Centos 7?

Tags: centos, php5, phpmyadmin, php7

I am using centos 7 and it came with php 5.4.16. Now i have to install moodle moodle 3.2 which requires at least PHP 5.6.5.

I tried installing php from remi and IUS repositories but no luck. All i get is error: conflict with the previous install.

If i install any other version of php phpmyadmin won't work. (I tried on development server it didn't work)

By the way I tried googling a lot..but ended up with not working solutions. SO I had to create this.

How do I acheive moodle and phpmyadmin both working on my server ?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Please check below

```
[root@intranet ~]# yum -y install php56u php56u-opcache php56u-xml php56u-mcrypt php56u-gd php56u-devel php56u-mysql php56u-intl php56u-mbstring php56u-bcmath
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.ehost.vn
 * epel: mirror.lzu.edu.cn
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * ius: mirror.amsiohosting.net
 * remi-safe: mirror.veriteknik.net.tr
 * updates: mirror.tadu.vn
 * webtatic: us-east.repo.webtatic.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-cli(x86-64) = 5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 for package: php56u-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-common(x86-64) = 5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 for package: php56u-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package php56u-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-devel.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pecl-jsonc-devel(x86-64) for package: php56u-devel-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package php56u-gd.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-intl.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-mcrypt.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-mysqlnd.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pdo(x86-64) = 5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 for package: php56u-mysqlnd-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package php56u-opcache.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-xml.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-cli.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-common.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pecl-jsonc(x86-64) for package: php56u-common-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
---> Package php56u-pdo.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
---> Package php56u-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64 0:1.3.10-2.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-pecl-jsonc.x86_64 0:1.3.10-2.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pear for package: php56u-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.ius.centos7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-pear for package: php56u-pecl-jsonc-1.3.10-2.ius.centos7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-pear.noarch 1:1.10.1-4.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php56u-posix for package: 1:php56u-pear-1.10.1-4.ius.centos7.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php56u-process.x86_64 0:5.6.29-1.ius.centos7 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php-mysql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64 conflicts php-mysqlnd
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-process-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-process < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-gd-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-gd < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-bcmath-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-bcmath < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-common-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-cli-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-cli < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-xml-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-xml < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-pdo-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-pdo < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-mysqlnd-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-mysql < 5.6
--> Processing Conflict: php56u-mbstring-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-mbstring < 5.6
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: php56u-bcmath conflicts with php-bcmath-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u-mbstring conflicts with php-mbstring-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u-gd conflicts with php-gd-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u conflicts with php-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php-mysql conflicts with php56u-mysqlnd-5.6.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
Error: php56u-mysqlnd conflicts with php-mysql-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u-process conflicts with php-process-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u-xml conflicts with php-xml-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u-pdo conflicts with php-pdo-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
Error: php56u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-42.el7.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix Stackexchange! You can [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) first and the learn [How to Ask a good question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). That makes it easier for us to help you.  In particular, the erorr message you gave shows two different things you can try, but you made no mention of your efforts in this regard.

Comment: I used php 7.1 from webstatic on Centos/SL 7.2 64 bit and phpmyadmin worked fine.But Cacti didnt work.When you want to downgrade it back to existing php. You should remove all include webtatic repos. I also got conflict problem when I didnt remove webtatic repos.

Comment: @StephenRauch I have made mention of my efforts. Please read carefully.

Comment: Yes, and you still have not taken the the tour, nor have you been explicit in telling about how you addressed these problems.  Your direction for me to read carefully misses the entire point of who is giving his time to whom.  It is incumbent on you to make it easy for others to answer your question, since it is you who is asking others to give you their valuable for free.

Comment: For anyone looking for the solution visit - https://asciinema.org/a/24503

Comment: Don't mix IUS, Remi, and Webtatic.  Pick one and stick with it.  In particular, Remi packages aggressively obsolete packages from other repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a brief guide [IUS Usage Guide](https://ius.io/Usage/).
In short you can try following:

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace
yum replace php --replace-with php56u
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been looking for this from days. Does the updates change anything later? How do i update to php 7 later?

Comment: @Vamshi, I think if there is php7 in `ius` repo the same way.

Comment: IUS has php70u and php71u available. By design, these are manual upgrades for you to switch to.

Answer (score 0):

**step:1**

```
CentOS/RHEL 7.x:

rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/epel-release.rpm
rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm

CentOS/RHEL 6.x:

rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el6/latest.rpm
```

**step:2**

Now you can install PHP 5.6 with an opcode cache by doing:

```
yum install php56w php56w-opcache
```

**step:3**

you can upgrade PHP by:

```
yum install yum-plugin-replace

yum replace --enablerepo=webtatic-testing php-common --replace-with=php56w-common
```